# Mostrar Tabla con NgFor en Angular6. Saca las columnas como filas

Tags: html, angular

quiero mostrar una tabla en Angular6, con el ngFor, el problema es que lo que debería ir en columnas, me sale en filas, es decir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar, está mal formado.

Este es mi código:

```
       <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="" *ngFor="let columna of result.columns; let i=index">{{ columna.name}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let j = index; let resultado of result.columns">
            <td *ngFor="let value of resultado.values">{{value.value}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Este el json de entrada.

```
{
  "result": "OK",
  "message": null,
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "Id-1",
      "order": 0,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "cf"
        },
        {
          "value": "13"
        },
        {
          "value": "9c"
        },
        {
          "value": "5a"
        },
        {
          "value": "1c"
        },
        {
          "value": "45"
        },
        {
          "value": "b"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "order": 1,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "prueba"
        },
        {
          "value": "TEST"
        },
        {
          "value": "Op"
        },
        {
          "value": "Op"
        },
        {
          "value": "P"
        },
        {
          "value": "PruebaTest"
        },
        {
          "value": "nal"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

¿ Cómo podría hacer para que se mostraran los datos correctamente ?. 
Los datos que deberían ir en la columna CF, me están saliendo a nivel de fila...

Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: mira como usar ng-template. para hacer que tu fila recorra las dos columnas.

Answer (score 2):

La solución

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td *ngFor="let d of data.columns">
     <table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    {{d.name}}
    </tr>

<tr *ngFor="let main of d.values">

   <td>
   {{main.value}} 
     </td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
    <td>

  </tr>
  </table>
```